# Trying to make a CSS3 diagonal slide animation, but it's not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

So I'm trying to create a diagonal scroll in CSS3, but I'm having no luck.
The original script is this: https://codepen.io/275845/pen/LoYBjg

```
  <style>
    .tech-slideshow {
      height: 600px;
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .tech-slideshow > div {
      height: 100px;
      width: 2526px;
      background: url(https://i2.wp.com/mitmark.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/circle.png?ssl=1);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .tech-slideshow .mover-1 {
      animation: moveSlideshow 12s linear infinite;
    }
    .tech-slideshow .mover-2 {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
      background-position: 0 -200px;
      animation: moveSlideshow 15s linear infinite;
    }


    @keyframes moveSlideshow {
      100% { 
        transform: translateX(-66.6666%);  
      }
    }
    </style>
<div class="tech-slideshow">
      <div class="mover-1"></div>
      <div class="mover-2"></div>
    </div>
```

Here's what I've tried so far, with no success: https://codepen.io/275845/pen/gJOjXY

```
<style>
.tech-slideshow {
  height: 600px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.tech-slideshow > div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 2526px;
  background: url(https://i2.wp.com/mitmark.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/circle.png?ssl=1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-1 {
  animation: moveSlideshow 2s linear infinite;
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  background-position: 0 -200px;
  animation: moveSlideshow 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes moveSlideshow {
   0% {
        transform: translatex(0px) translatey(0px)
    }
    100% {
        transform: translatex(100px) translatey(100px);
    }
}
</style>
```

And here's the result that I'm trying to achieve: https://streamable.com/ltsba

As you can see, I'm trying to make a diagonal slide scrolling in css3, but of course, if anyone could point me out another solution weather it's vanilla javascript, or even jQuery, I'm opened for new suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, just a few issues.

1. You don't need 2 "mover", one is enough.
2. Make it big! And background repeat!
3. Then you move the size of that background image.

```
.tech-slideshow > div {
  height: 3000px;  // BIG
  width: 3000px;
  background: url(https://i2.wp.com/mitmark.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/circle.png?ssl=1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;. // position
  right: 0;
  animation: moveSlideshow 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
    0% {
        transform: translatex(0px) translatey(0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translatex(255px) translatey(255px);  // move size of image
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but why's the background not acting like a repetitive tile?

Comment: Dont get your point. I have it act like the video you linked already.

Comment: I get it now, it's the "translatex(294px) translatey(294px);" part; It should be the same size as the image. It's that I've changed the image. But why's the scroll bar changing size both vertically and horizontally? I'm going to use this as a background for a site.